# Cannot "read further comments " or add comments

Tags: support, comments, ios

For a week now I cannot add comments, or use the blue "view more comments" or flag questions.
How to fix this?

A week ago when travelling I had the captcha option happen on all my comments and answers. That stopped when I got home.
I had thought it was because I was too active on stackexchange, but when I used a laptop (or the app on this tablet) there are no restrictions at all.

Same on each SE site, regardless of reputation (e.g 1000)
Tried logging out and in again.

Using Safari 9.0 (the latest permissible) on ipad 2 with iOS 9.3.5

Tried using Dolphin Browser, didn't work there either. (Cannot use chrome, firefox etc on this old iOS). Tried clearing safari cache and history.

When I hit "Add a Comment" or "flag" it just jumps to the top of the question. I can still answer questions, but with none of the text formatting options or no picture adding available.

Cannot up- or down- vote. When I am logged out, or on sites where I am not a member, e.g Aviation, I can use the blue show further comments button!

Not sure if this is a problem with my account, or change of SE software.

Comment: Can you try with other browser app on your device?

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: You are using a browser which isn't supported by SE anymore. Your best bet, as much as I personally dislike it, is installing the iOS app of Stack Exchange and using it. Good luck!

Comment: As a warning the iOS app hasnt been maintained for a few years and will not be maintained in the future. As soon as something serious breaks the app it is done for.

Comment: Might be related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349484/when-i-try-to-add-a-comment-the-question-is-restarted-why Do answers work?

Comment: @Luuklag well at least they'll be able to post comments using it.

Comment: @samcarter OP can't comment so I'll copy the reply here and edit it out of the question: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349484/when-i-try-to-add-a-comment-the-question-is-restarted-why) is very similar, except after a jump to the top of the question, I still cannot type a comment. I can still answer questions.